# Parsing a string of comma separated values

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

What would be the most elegant way to extract values from a string of comma-separated numbers?

It should account for whitespaces too. Example:

Input string: `"22,10,8,13"`
Input string: `"22,  10,   8,   13"`
Input string: `"22, 10 ,8 ,13,"`

Given all three inputs, the method should recognise the values. 
Example output for all three inputs: `"String contains: 22 10 8 13"`

Possible duplicate: [Easiest way to parse a comma delimited string to some kind of object I can loop through to access the individual values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235683/easiest-way-to-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-to-some-kind-of-object-i-can-loop)

Comment: Did you try anything? Have you checked out LINQ?

Comment: @Default using LINQ for a simple `string.Split(',')` job? its overkill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string input = "22,10 ,8 , 13";
var output = input.Split(',').Select(i=>i.Trim());
```