# Get a specific value from comma separated string

Tags: c#, string

I have a instrument which returns me a string value as this

```
string var = "0,0,0.1987,22.13";
```

I want to use only the 4th value "22.13". I tried with `Trim()` and `Replace()` methods but couldn't exactly get what I want. How to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Easiest way to parse a comma delimited string to some kind of object I can loop through to access the individual values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235683/easiest-way-to-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-to-some-kind-of-object-i-can-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
string data = "0,0,0.1987,22.13";
string value = data.Split(',')[3];
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Split` method is the best to use here!

The `Split` method does what it says on the lid. It splits a string into different parts at a character separator that you specify. e.g. `"Hello World".Split(' ')` splits the string into a `string[]` that contains `{"Hello", "World"}`.

So in this case, you can split the string by `','`:

```
var.Split (',') //Use single quotes! It's of type char
```

If you want to access the fourth item, use an indexer! (of course)

```
var.Split(',')[3] //Remember to use 3 instead of 4! It's zero based!
```

Now you can happily store the string in some variable

```
string fourthThing = var.Split (',')[3];
```

Additional Information:

The `Split` method also has a overload that takes a `char` and a `StringSplitOptions`. If you do something like this:

```
var.Split (',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Empty entries will be automatically removed! How good!

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

To pick up the last element, you can use Split function and Linq as below

```
string GetLastElement(string data) {
   return data.Split(',').Last();
}
```