# How to get second values from a string (comma-separated value) in C#

Tags: c#

As I want to remove a comma-separated value from the string and get Second Value.

Suppose I have a string like this

```
string x="12,1108,06"
```

and I want to remove commas from that string, and I want Second Value Only

```
string x="1108"
```

From the above string I want to remove all the values and I want to keep only the second value.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to parse a comma delimited string to some kind of object I can loop through to access the individual values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235683/easiest-way-to-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-to-some-kind-of-object-i-can-loop)

Comment: Have you tried `string Split function`? whats the difficulty that you faced?

Comment: @TheerthaDinesh: then why don't you access the `1st` element of the resulted array of `split()`

Comment: @ilkerkaran.Thank You.But I want to get only the 2 values from my string.That Link is not working for me.Is there any Method for this??

Comment: @sujithkarivelil. Thank You For The Answer.Yes I tried split function.Removes only commas

Comment: @TheerthaDinesh: So `x` is the input string that you are having and you want to perform the split operation, remove commas and store the updated value `1108` in `x`, is that the requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split(char)`

```
string x = "12,1108,06";
var result = x.Split(',').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

or

```
string x = "12,1108,06";
var result = x.Split(',')[1];
```

Comment: @TheerthaDinesh: This is what I commented above *why don't you access the 1st element of the resulted array of split()* that is `x.Split(',')[1]`

Comment: @TheerthaDinesh: So the string.Split method IS working then!!!

Comment: anything wrong here or why the down vote

Comment: @Dr.Snail.Can I ask you one more thing,
If my string contains value 12,ie,
string x = "12";
Then
var result = x.Split(',')[1]; --- Return null value.
Is there any method to check whether my string contains 2nd value or not??

Comment: @TheerthaDinesh `int numberofelements = x.Split(',').Count()`

Comment: @Dr.Snail.Thank you for the answers.It works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = x.Split(',')?.Skip(1)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Trim();
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for Trim()

Comment: @Amir-no-family. Thank You For the Answer.But Its Not Working

Comment: @TheerthaDinesh  then you might want to edit your question a bit to tell us what you are expecting exactly!

Comment: @Toshi the word Trim in the title confused me but using Trim is a good idea nevertheless to get rid of spaces.